# Difference between "except" and "besides"

Tags: prepositions, differences

What is the difference between *except* and *besides*? When do we use each of them?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They have totally different meanings, in fact opposite in some sense. *Except* serves the purpose of *exclusion* while *besides* serves that of *inclusion*.

Suppose John is in a class of 30 students. If the other 29 students are going to the zoo but John is not, we say

> The whole class is going, except John.

Now suppose Mary from another class is also going to the zoo. Then we say

> Besides the class, Mary is also going.

Comment: What about ‘I have no other family besides my parents’?